# Remove quantity for individual items on magento product page

Tags: php, magento

My first post, i have code where i can individually remove add-to-cart options from products using an additional attribute in the back end, added in addtocart.phtml.

The problem i am having is that i do not want this to affect the add to cart button just the quantity box and label.

I have tried many variations and nothing seems to help, i am thinking that i have this code inserted in an incorrect file but i am not sure.

You can see the code below, i was wondering if anyone could assist me in amending this code in order to achieve the functionality that i am looking for:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php $attTest= $_product->getData(); ?>
<?php if($attTest['sell_online']): ?>
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <div class="add-to-cart">
            <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Number of weeks:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo   $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Number of Weeks') ?>"  class="input-text qty" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button   btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update this answer for any of the community members searching for this solution, my thanks go out to Satish the cleaver dude who helped me with my predicament and the original code provider who gave me the idea.

So firstly create an attribute so that you can turn quantity on and off (quantity_active), set catalog input type for store owner to yes/no.

Then copy and paste the following code over the code that exists in your addtocart.phtml.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php $attTest= $_product->getData(); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class ="add-to-cart"></div>   
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
<?php if($attTest['quantity_active']): ?>
<strong><label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Number of Weeks:') ?></label></strong>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty             ($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Number of Weeks') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<?php endif; ?>
<div class ="clear"></div>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart"       onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?  ></span></span></button>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you should now be able to switch the quantity option on and off. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Set hints for template on to get .phtml and block class involved.
Cross check if block class in local folder.

Also check if compiler mode is on in that case your file will be in inc class folder.

Once you make sure you have modify right file then :
assuming that if $attTest sell online is the needed variable value.

```
 <?php if($attTest['sell_online']): ?>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Number of weeks:') ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo          $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Number of Weeks') ?>"  class="input-text qty" />
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry I am a novice with the code, I have checked the block and it seems to be product view, the phtml is addtocart.  I have added the code but it doesn't seem to be achieving anything I am sure this is my lack of skill with the code, any further information would be much appreciated.  Thanks Satish!

Comment: I am not sure I checked with hints and it seems to inform me that addtocart.phtml is the file I need to edit Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View, I already have the code you gave added in addtocart.phtml a little unsure what to do from there to be honest.  Your help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Just to be sure I want to always keep add to cart button with this attribute and turn quantity on and off.  Thanks Again I've be looking at this for two days now very frustrating!

Comment: I edited My answer.Also did you change some string and confirmed that this is the .phtml that will have effect.

Comment: thank you satish that sorted it, all works fine now.  Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is great except that if any product doesn't have the attribute, an error will be thrown. Best to change the `if` test slightly:

```
<?php if (empty($attTest['quantity_active']) || false) :?>
```

This just checks to see if the attribute exists or is set for the product.